# windows trying to run an executable with co-workers path

Tags: python, powershell, pip, environment

See the image:
[image]

This has absolutly driven me up a wall.  How does powershell or windows, know to try and prefix the run pip command with my coworkers system path?  I'm thinking something must have gotten commited into our repo, but I'm pulling my hair out to find it.  Anyone know where this can come about?  I've checked environment variables for python and path, but no luck.  Its weird that it doesn't just run my stuff, that it even tries to prefix it all...

Comment: Yeppers, strange. I'd agree without that any modules on your system from the repo that got updated, that is using temp path assignments, might be the culprit. Though unless that is a shared location with you having perms for it, it should jut fail outright.

Comment: @postanote - do you know any other way of checking path assignments other than `dir env:`  Those paths come out clean for me.

Comment: As last resort, [Procmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) can be used to track all process activities. Using that could pick up configuration files and whatnot that are read during process execution. It will create quite a big log.

Comment: Not off the top of my head. I usually check PS and Raw Windows paths separately to be sure of stuff. Yet, this is just too odd.... time for some experiements to see if it can repor'd.